# Transfer form together with other data using one AJAX post. Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x

Very simple task. It is necessary to transfer data from the form together with other data using AJAX POST. The problem is how to extract this data later from the form, because they represent a whole line.

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form=$('#myform').serialize();
    var data={};
    data['form']=form;
    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken']='{{ csrf_token }}';
    data['other_data']='other_data';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/myajaxformview',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $('#output2').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, e) {
            alert(status, e);
        }
    });
  });
});

def myajaxformview(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            data = request.POST
            print(data)
            #<QueryDict: {'form': ['csrfmiddlewaretoken=VtBJ03YJZsEocJ5sxl9RqATdu38QBPgu4yPAC64JlpjOzILlF1fOQj54TotABHx9&field1=1&field2=2'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['VtBJ03YJZsEocJ5sxl9RqATdu38QBPgu4yPAC64JlpjOzILlF1fOQj54TotABHx9'], 'other_data': ['other_data']}>
            form=data.get('form')
            #csrfmiddlewaretoken=VtBJ03YJZsEocJ5sxl9RqATdu38QBPgu4yPAC64JlpjOzILlF1fOQj54TotABHx9&field1=1&field2=2
            print(form)
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data))
    return render(request, 'foo.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using of `FormData`:

```
$(function() {
  $('#myform').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData(event.target);
    data.append('form', event.target);
    data.append('csrfmiddlewaretoken', '{{ csrf_token }}');
    data.append('other_data', 'other_data');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/myajaxformview',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
           $('#output2').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, e) {
          alert(status, e);
        }
    });
  });
 });
```

Comment: Wow! It `s Magic! I'm a beginner and have suffered for this task for several days, and you gave me a decision so quickly, thank you very much!